# Twig Setting Select Option on a dropdown

Tags: php, templates, twig

I am currently writing a php mvc  from scratch and using twig as my template engine and need some assistance setting the selected option on a drop down list. Currently in my model I have an sql query that pull all list of supervisors and drops them in my drop down list using the twig for loop but I need to some how select a user’s supervisor if it matches up.

I apologize now as I am new to twig

View:

```
<select class="form-control" id="supervisor">
      {% for supervisor in supervisor %}
      <option value="{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}" >{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Tried:

```
<select class="form-control" id="supervisor">
      {% for supervisor in supervisor %}
{% if {{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}} == {{ user.supervisor }} %}
            <option value=”{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}” selected>{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}</option>
{% else %}
    <option value=”{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}”>{{supervisor.fname}} {{supervisor.lname}}</option>
{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May be you can try something like this: 
Replace `supervisor` variable name by `oneSupervisor` in the loop and test `oneSupervisor` with `user.supervisor`.

```
<select class="form-control" id="supervisor">
    {% for oneSupervisor in supervisor %}
        {% set selected = '' %}
        {% if (oneSupervisor.fname ~ ' ' ~ oneSupervisor.lname) == user.supervisor %}
           {% set selected = 'selected' %}
        {% endif %}
        <option value="{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}" {{ selected }}>{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: This is still not setting the select value but I am pretty sure I know why... 

the table the query is pulling from has a first and last name column and the oneSupervisor var that is being set is not returning the name frist and last name. i attempted to set a var of supervisr like  {% set moose = 'oneSupervisor.fname oneSupervisor.lname' %} an using that in the if statement but it still not setting selected

Comment: What do you have in `supervisor` and in `user.supervisor`?

Comment: User.supervisor returns it as one string Bob Smith onesupervisor is an array (fname Bob lname Smith) of it would be easier I could create a new table that just houses all the supervisors

Comment: @darkdelusions: I change my if  test with concatenation

Comment: Thank you @doydoy44 that corrected the issue I didn't even think about concatenating the the 2 together.

Comment: @darkdelusions: You're welcome and thank's for your return :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a form called `form` and therein a select field called `field`, You could simply do the following:

```
{% do form.field.setRendered %}
<select id="{{ form.field.vars.id }}" 
        name="{{ form.field.vars.name }}"> 
    {% for option in form.field.vars.choices %}
        <option {{ form.field.vars.value == option.value ? 'selected' : '' }} 
                value="{{ option.value }}">
            {{ option.label }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```