# Is it good to calculate which items will be selected before passing array to template?

Tags: design-patterns, twig

I have learned that in templates there should not be much logic.

Once I decided to do this when I needed to render dropdown.

Instead of this because there is logic for getting selected:
copied from answer here: [Twig Setting Select Option on a dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630410/twig-setting-select-option-on-a-dropdown)

```
<select class="form-control" id="supervisor">
    {% for oneSupervisor in supervisor %}
        {% set selected = '' %}
        {% if (oneSupervisor.fname ~ ' ' ~ oneSupervisor.lname) == user.supervisor %}
           {% set selected = 'selected' %}
        {% endif %}
        <option value="{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}" {{ selected }}>{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Would do this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="supervisor">
    {% for oneSupervisor in supervisor %}
        <option value="{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}" {{ oneSupervisor.selected }}>{{oneSupervisor.fname}} {{oneSupervisor.lname}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

So as you can see I removed logic calculating if is selected.

oneSupervisor.selected is calculated before passing supervisor to the template.

Is this good or bad? My colleagues argued that its too complicated. I do not see it more complicated, only that the supervisor items is extended by one key.

Did not test the code, so might be errors, but that's not the point here.

Comment: Why voting for close? In case you think it is opinion based, I think it is good practice and code quality based.

Answer (score 0):

*This is primary opinion based though. Anyhow my 2 cents on this issue*

---

What you suggested can be usefull if you have a lot of comboboxes where u'd need to define the selected one. As you did not provide us the details on how you set the property `selected` on the values i'm imagining you did this in the controller with a `loop`. As you would have a lot of comboboxes you would have a lot of redundant code, which is bad.

I'm not sure you are working with objects or not but lets say you are then i'm sure every object would have an unique `id` in there to distinct which object is which then it would be beter to solve this with a `trait`

<kbd>Selectable.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    trait Selectable {
        public function isSelected($object) {
            return $this->getId() === $object->getId();
        }
    }
```

By doing so you can give the trait to each object that could be selected e.g.

<kbd>User.php</kbd>

```
<?php   
    class User {
        use Selectable;

        protected $id;
        protected $supervisor = null;
        protected $city = null;

        public function setId($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getId() {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function setSupervisor(User $supervisor) {
            $this->supervisor = $supervisor;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getSupervisor() {
            return $this->supervisor;
        }

        public function setCity(City $city) {
            $this->city = $city;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getCity() {
            return $this->city;
        }           
    }
```

<kbd>City.php</kbd>

```
<?php
    class City {
        use Selectable;

        protected $id;

        public function setId($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getId() {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

Now you don't need to worry anywore on writing the logic to check whether something is selected and you can use it freely in `twig`

<kbd>twig</kbd>

```
<select name="supervisor">
{% for supervisor in supervisors %}
    <option value="{{ supervisor.id }}" {% if user.supervisor.isSelected(user.getSupervisor()) %} selected{% endif %}>{{ supervisor.getName() }} {{ supervisor.getFirstName() }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>


<select name="cities">
{% for city in cities %}
    <option value="{{ city.id }}" {% if city.isSelected(user.getCity()) %} selected{% endif %}>{{ city.getZipcoded() }} {{ city.getName() }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

If you are using `doctrine` or `propel` you could even modify the model generator by injecting the `Selectable trait` in every model thus saving you the problem of identifing which object is selectable

Comment: "{% if city.isSelected(user.getCity()) %} selected{% endif %}" still this is lot of code in template. Practically same amout as if there was no isSelected function. So you did not "sold" to me this.

Comment: "a lot of code" - Then I don't know what you tbh. You still need to have an if somewhere in there. As I said, this is a setup where you have a lot of objects where u need to determine if it's selected or not

Comment: In my example I do not have if in template. Thats the question if it is good to do.

Comment: You do have one in your controller though. Anyway imho just doing `{{ object.selected }}` is not straight forward enough. I mean i'm sure this could cause confusing for other developers going through your code and they would have to look inside your controller to determine what that property returns.

Comment: Another point I would make is that using the `if` inside the template is not a bad thing. What if you wanted to use the same pattern to test if a menu-item is selected? In this case I just could use my same logic and do something in the line of `<a href="object.getRoute() }}" {% if object.isSelected() %} class="active"{% endif %}>{{ object.getName() }}</a>`

Comment: do note this is just my view on how to handle this and i'm not claiming to be right nor you being wrong

Comment: lot of things developers need to go to controller or other cllass to see how it was calculated. So that how 'selected' is calculated would be no exception.

Comment: Not realy as doing the `if` inside the template or `object.isSelected(...)` is self-explanatory